# Comparison operators - if / else if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

This exercise was already posted here a few years ago [How to use comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930228/how-to-use-comparison-operators) however the solution presented is not working for me.

The question is:

> On the editor to your right you find a variable named charmanderLevel,
> to which a value between 1 and 100 will be assigned.
>
> Using else if statements print to the console which evolution of
> Charmander corresponds to that experience level. Consider an else
> statement if the experience level ever go above 100 that should print
> 'Charizard is as good as it gets '.
>
> Here's a chart with the evolution which corresponds to each level:
>
> Charmander - 1 to 15 Charmeleon - 16 to 35 Charizard - 36 to 100"

The solution was

```js
var charmanderLevel = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);

if (charmanderLevel >= 1 && charmanderLevel <= 15) {
  console.log('Charmander');
} else if (charmanderLevel >= 16 && charmanderLevel <= 35) {
  console.log('Charmeleon');
} else if (charmanderLevel >= 36 && charmanderLevel <= 100) {
  console.log('Charizard');
} else {
  console.log('Charizard is as good as it gets');
}
```

And I created literally the same

```js
var charmanderLevel = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);

if (charmanderLevel >= 1 && charmanderLevel <= 15) {
  console.log("Charmander");
} else if (charmanderLevel >= 16 && charmanderLevel <= 35) {
  console.log("Charmeleon");
} else if (charmanderLevel >= 36 && charmanderLevel <= 100) {
  console.log("Charizard");
} else {
  console.log('Charizard is good as it gets');
}
```

But my console keeps saying

> "Code is incorrect You should only print to the console the Charmander evolution level, nothing else".

They suggested that I opened a new question regarding this to ask to some of you some lights please, why it worked for some and mine is not.

Thanks

Comment: Have you used some tool to see the exact differences between your code and the example (working) code? Have you tried to run your code in a local environment to see its actual output? Is the code you show us here an exact, full and complete copy-paste of the code submitted to whatever site you use for checking?

Comment: So not "literally", I guess. :) Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: I guess I founded now that the fisrt level had to star on 0 and not 1. Thanks

Comment: Neither of the two code snippets will explicitly handle the case when `charmanderLevel == 0`. And `charmanderLevel` will never be equal or larger than `100` (as [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will never return `1`). So both attempts are flawed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I t is resolved! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a file comparer to see the slightly detail.

In case of level > 100, your message is "Charizard is good as it gets", you miss the little "as" of the right answer.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30142010/17580844) show how to compare files in vscode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Now I was able to find the other error.